# Express and SSR, dealing with multilanguage

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I'm implementing SSR on Adobe AEM, and it allows me to do SSR for just some routes of the application. My application is made in ReactJS and I'm using Express to do the server-side rendering.

In the body of the request that the express server receives I have all the translations. To apply the translations to the app I have this function, **which is used throughout the project thousands of times, and NOT all of them inside a component**.

```
export const getDictionaryEntry = (text, hint, variables) => {
    if (hint == null) {
        hint = 'ABC';
    }
    if (PathUtils.isBrowser()) {
        let output = window.Granite.I18n.get(text, variables, hint);
        if (output == text) {
            //dictionary entry with comment not found.  Return dictionary entry without comment.
            output = window.Granite.I18n.get(text, variables, null);
        }
        return output;
    }
    else {
        // server side rendering
    }
    return text;
};
```

Knowing that passing the dictionary as a parameter to this function is not an option, I've been trying to work my way around using global:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const lang = req.header('ssrLanguage') || 'en';
    if(typeof global.ssrTranslations === 'undefined') {
        global.ssrTranslations = {};
        global.ssrTranslations[lang] = req.body.ssrTranslations || {};
    }
    else {
        global.ssrTranslations[lang] = req.body.ssrTranslations || {};
    }
    delete req.body.ssrTranslations;
    next();
});
```

This is not yet fully implemented but I would like to avoid using global also because the function `getDictionaryEntry` doesn't receive the language of the request, thus I'd have to find a way to also track the language of the current request.

Is there a way from the react code to get a variable from the express and this variable to exist only in the request? How could I do it?

Thanks for any help